# Flex toolbar wrapping while sticking to the left/right side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm designing a toolbar that wraps depending on the width and has two halves, with outermost items sticking to their respective side:

[image: 1]

The container has `justify-content: flex-end` set. As it gets narrower, last items get wrapped, but stick to the end as expected:

[image]

`Spacer` is just a `margin: 0 auto` element.

[image]

However as soon as one of the left items is wrapped, the rest suddenly jumps to the right:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this jump?

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/XNJeoSqDMe8DtgWj7KfZ?p=preview

Comment: One possible solution would be to set a media `breakpoint` at that width and adjust the placement

Answer (score 0):

Because you flex end on the container, I can't see how you can make it keep left.

you can use a media query. to change the flex-end to start but then its all left aligned.

the other solution would be to let it grow to the full container. at the small screen

```
.toolbar > * {
flex-grow:1
}
```

sorry could't be more help.